# How to move footer to the space of margin-bottom space used in @page

Tags: html, css, itext, margin, flying-saucer

I have the following @page

```
@page {
    size: 210mm 297mm;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15%; // eliminates the page size on the bottom
}
```

I need to show footer to this left-out margin using `flying-saucer-pdf` version 9.1.22.

I tried the following code but it's not working:

```
@media print {
        div.divFooter {
                margin-bottom: -15% !important; // I need to take advantage of the free space of @page margin bottom
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                height: 80px;
                z-index: 1; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#running-elements), [this](https://printcss.blog/printcss-running-headers-and-footers-3bef60a60d62) and [this](https://www.quackit.com/css/at-rules/css_bottom-left-corner_at-rule.cfm) pages.

```
@page {
   size: 210mm 297mm;
   background: white;
   margin-bottom: 2.3cm;
   @bottom-left {
      vertical-align: top;
      content: element(footer);
      padding-top: 1px;
      border-top:1px solid #777;
   }
   @bottom-center {
      border-top:1px solid #777;
   }
   @bottom-right {
      border-top:1px solid #777;
   }

}
footer {
   margin-top: 0.1cm;
   display: block;
   position: running(footer);
   font-size: 8pt;
   line-height:1.0;
}
```

And my html code contains the following element:

```
<footer>
   <p style="font-size: 10pt;"><b>Note(s)</b></p>
   <p>This is a printed copy.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Do not use position: block in `body` or `@page` because `running()` won't work.